# Run an MSBuild target only for projects which do not have a specific package reference

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I have a `Directory.build.targets` file which contains a `<Target>...</Target>` that runs before building the projects in the directory. This target checks a couple conditions (one, that a specific project property is set correctly, and the other, that a specific project reference has a metadata item set correctly). This works just fine.

However, I would like the target to skip certain projects in the directory. Specifically, I would like to skip "unit test projects", where "unit test projects" is (I guess, nowadays) defined as "has a `<PackageReference>` to "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk". That's a good enough proxy for me.

If I add a message like this:

```
<Message
    Text="this is the message, for $(MSBuildProjectName)"
    Importance="high"
    Condition="'%(PackageReference.FileName)' != 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'" />
```

The message is written out for each of the projects that I DO want the target to apply to. However, this condition can't be applied to the target itself; this results in the following error:

```
 error MSB4116: The condition "'%(PackageReference.FileName)' != 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'" on the "ValidateModuleProjectProperties" target has a reference to item metadata. References to item metadata are not allowed in target conditions unless they are part of an item transform.
```

I tried the related (allowed) form of the condition, `@(PackageReference->'$(FileName)') != 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'`, but that doesn't work (which is probably obvious to someone who understands the difference, but I do not...).

I tried adding the condition using an `And` operator to the `<Error .../>` item, but that didn't seem to have any effect:

```
<Error
    Condition="$(EnableDynamicLoading) != true And '%(PackageReference.FileName)' != 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'"
    Text="The EnableDynamicLoading property must be set to true for non-test projects."
    ContinueOnError="false" />
```

I tried putting a `<Choose><When Condition="">...</When></Choose>` inside my target, but it appears that that construct is not allowed.

How can I cause this target to only apply to non-"test" projects?

Answer (score 3):

I created a new test project from the 'MSTest Test Project' template and the new project has the following:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Your project may be different. That's okay. I'm using the above as an example.

The following expression is incorrect

```
@(PackageReference->'$(FileName)')
```

- Use `Identity`, not `Filename`. `Filename` excludes what appears to be a file extension. For 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk', `Filename` is 'Microsoft.NET.Test'. `Identity` is the value from the `Include`.
- In a transform a metadata value starts with `%`, not `$`.

e.g. with fixes applied

```
@(PackageReference->'%(Identity)')
```

But that still won't work because that evaluates to a string that is a list of all the names.

e.g. given the above `PackageReference`s

```
"'@(PackageReference->'%(Identity)')' != 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'"
```

evaluates to

```
"'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk;MSTest.TestAdapter;MSTest.TestFramework;coverlet.collector' != 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'"
```

which is always true.

A property can be set based on if the `PackageReference` collection has a certain item. [Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-metadata-in-task-batching?view=vs-2022) will help to do that but a `Target` is needed for batching.

```xml
  <Target Name="DefineIsTestProject">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <IsTestProject>false</IsTestProject>
      <IsTestProject Condition="'%(PackageReference.Identity)' == 'Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk'">true</IsTestProject>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

The `DefineIsTestProject` target sets the `IsTestProject` property to `true` for test projects and `false` otherwise.

The `%(PackageReference.Identity)` is splitting the `@(PackageReference)` collection into batches per unique values of `Identity`. The property definition is run for each batch. Batching is **not** iteration but `Identity` is unique per item in the collection so effectively this is visiting and testing each item in the collection.

The following doesn't work.

```xml
  <!-- Broken - Don't use this -->
  <Target Name="ValidateModuleProjectProperties" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="DefineIsTestProject" Condition="!$(IsTestProject)">
    ...
```

The `Condition` is tested before running the `Target`s in the `DependsOnTargets`. This may seem like a 'quirk' but is actually very useful behavior.

There are two ways around this.

1. Move the `Condition` to an element within the `Target`.

```xml
  <Target Name="ValidateModuleProjectProperties" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="DefineIsTestProject">
    <Error Condition="!$(IsTestProject) and '$(EnableDynamicLoading)' != 'true'" .../>
    ...
```

2. For more complex situations, create an 'orchestrator' `Target` that arranges the order of other `Target`s.

```xml
  <Target Name="RunValidateModuleProjectProperties" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="DefineIsTestProject;ValidateModuleProjectProperties"/>

  <Target Name="ValidateModuleProjectProperties" Condition="!$(IsTestProject)">
    ...
```